# Checking if already have the information in database

Tags: php

I need check if a register that I'm trying to insert are already on my database, but my code isn't working, anyone can help me?
This is my code to check:

```
 $query1 = sqlsrv_num_rows(sqlsrv_query("SELECT * FROM carro WHERE placa = '$placa'"));
    if ($query1 == 1) {
        echo "<script>alert('usuario já existe.'); history.back();</script>";
    }
```

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234… then return here and do the same with the tick/check mark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Answer (score 3):

You didn't pass connection object to `sqlsrv_query`, so query is not running:-

```
$query1 = sqlsrv_num_rows(sqlsrv_query($your_database_connection_object_variable,"SELECT * FROM carro WHERE placa = '$placa'")); // provide your data base connection object as first parameter
    if (count($query1) >= 1) {
        echo "<script>alert('usuario já existe.'); history.back();</script>";
    }
```

Note:- I am astonished that your code not raising any error to you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I tried use your code, but it doesn't work, i put this line: print_r( sqlsrv_errors()); 
to see if i have any return, and i got this:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -50 [code] => -50 [2] => This function only works with statements that have static or keyset scrollable cursors. [message] => This function only works with statements that have static or keyset scrollable cursors. ) )

Comment: @FernandoKowacic  its your responsibility to check the answer and mark and up-vote the answer which is correct and more descriptive for you. Please do it. It will help others. Stack work in this way only.